# Bugzilla bz_webservice_demo.pl is errs out with 500

Tags: perl, bugzilla

perl contrib/bz_webservice_demo.pl --uri http://bugzilla.example.com/xmlrpc.cgit always errs out with 500 Error for Bugzilla.version.

error.log show that

```
xmlrpc.cgi: Can't use an undefined value as a subroutine reference at lib/SOAP/Transport/HTTP.pm line 384
```

If I hit another well know server like bugzilla.redhat.com ; it shows version perfectly. That means this server problem and not client related.

Bugzilla version 4.4.6
Uname - Ubuntu 14

Comment: I have partly solved this. There is function / codered it is expecting at that line. I have commented offending line then there was another place I have seed same problem and commented again. xmlrpc worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In this file: `bugzilla/lib/SOAP/Transport/HTTP.pm`, comment out lines 384 and 452. These lines both pass some value to a new `debug_logger` that didn't exist in the SOAP/HTTP module in my previous Bugzilla installation. Since we're not trying to debug this module, there is no need for those lines anyway.

It's worth pointing out that the SOAP module is not part of Bugzilla's own code, and is not included with the files you download. It gets installed during the setup process. This means it doesn't matter what Bugzilla version you're running. This is something that was changed in the SOAP module, so if you tried to reinstall an older version of Bugzilla, it wouldn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same on Ubuntu14 and Fedora20 Bugzilla4.4.6 boxes.

"500 internal server error", no bugzilla/errorlog entries,
but /var/log/httpd/error_log shows
xmlrpc.cgi: Can't use an undefined value as a subroutine reference at lib/SOAP/Transport/HTTP.pm line 384.

The perl cgi script needs to be debugged right?